# Xamarin Forms Admob MarcTron banner isn't loaded on start

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

In my xamarin forms app, i can load a banner from a button click calling banner.LoadAd();
I want to be called automatically on page load, but when i call it from the constructor or from the OnAppearing it does not load it.
In OnAppearing, when i minimize the app and reload it, it works fine.
Only the first time isnt loaded.